# Is this grammar LR(0) or SLR(1)

Tags: compiler-construction, grammar

I have a question related to a grammar:

```
S --> ( S ) S | S --> epsilon.
```

So is this grammar LR(0) or SLR(1)? I have provided the NFA and DFA of it but I am stuck on the parsing table.[NFA and DFA of the grammar above mentioned](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7dxXr.jpg)

In my opinion this is a SLR(0) grammar because every state contains `S --> .` because of the epsilon, and so every state with this production has a Shift-Reduce conflict.

Comment: @close-voter This question does not ‘need more focus’. It has a yes-or-no answer which back in the day I would have been able to provide myself, but my studies in this area were 44 years ago. I am confident that rici or another expert here will answer it correctly. There is a big difference between ’needs more focus’ and ‘I don’t know anything about this matter’.

Answer (score 1):

The grammar is not LR(0) because (as you point out) there are shift-reduce conflicts in the LR(0) automaton.

It also isn't SLR(0) because that's the same as LR(0).

It looks to me like it's SLR(1), because FOLLOW(S) is ')' and the end-marker (which you omit from your analysis), and that would be enough to resolve the conflicts.